# Android with Facebook long lived access token

Tags: android, facebook, laravel, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I'm developing an Android app backed by Laravel.

In the app I sign in the user with the Facebook SDK (com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton) and get the Facebook access token.

This token is sent to the server which get a long lived access token through the Facebook sdk and send it back to the app.

So later in the account creation process the app can request the user's Facebook albums with the long lived access token (in can be during the account creation process or later in the app profile preferences…)

My problem is when I make a Facebook graph api request to get the album list, I get an error :

`{HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 2500, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.}`

serveur: graph api version: v2.5
app: facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0

Comment: i've just tried to debug the facebook access token on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/ and the token sent by my web app server is fine (token, expir date,…)

Comment: doesn't the android SDK already give you a long lived access token ? you do not need to get another long lived token from it from what i understand.

Comment: unfortunately i already ckeck if the received token if long lived before asking for a new long lived access token like this :

```if (! $facebook_access_token->isLongLived()) { […] }```